# transparent navigation bar leaves a dark box

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, transparency, android-jetpack-compose

```kotlin
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar(items: List<BottomNavItem>, navController: NavController, onItemClick: (BottomNavItem) -> Unit){
    val selectedScreen = navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    BottomNavigation(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,

    ) {
        items.forEach { item ->
            val selected = item.route == selectedScreen.value?.destination?.route
            BottomNavigationItem(
                selected = selected,
                onClick = { onItemClick(item) },
                selectedContentColor = colorResource(id = R.color.button_background_light_blue),
                unselectedContentColor = Color.Gray,
                icon = {
                    Column(horizontalAlignment = CenterHorizontally) {
                        Icon(imageVector = item.icon, contentDescription = item.name)
                        if(selected) {
                            Text(text = item.name, textAlign = TextAlign.Center, fontSize = 10.sp)
                        }
                    }
                }
            )

        }
    }
}
```

[image: you can see the box here]
[image: and here]
[image]

tbh I haven't found anything about (that's just what I assume) a box that contains icons or anything close to that, what could I add to remove that "box"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the elevation to 0.dp. I don't know the exact method for `BottomNavigation`, but if there is a parameter named `elevation`, set it to 0.dp. If there is no parameter value with that name, apply the elevation Modifier.

`Modifier.elevation(0.dp)`

Comment: If your problem is resolved, mark the solution as the correct answer. There is a little grey tick below the votes. Just tick that. If you have any other issues, just inform me. It is to help others know that the query has been resolved.